# Invalid grant error on WSO2 IS using special characters in the password with grant_type=password

Tags: special-characters, wso2-identity-server

I have an app that conects to WSO2 to generate its access token and refresh token, but when I use special characters in the password, the server answers with an invalid grant error

Im testing it with postman with this url:

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=XXXXX&password=123Abc$#

Basic auth with OAuth client key and secret and Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

The answer is:

```
{
  "error_description": "Authentication failed for Ceiba2@carbon.super",
  "error": "invalid_grant"
}
```

Is there any way to scape these special characters? because WSO2 allows me to change the password to use special characters both from the app directly and using its SOAP service.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I solved it encoding the url characters

The final url was:

https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token?grant_type=password&username=XXXXXX&password=123Abc%24%23